# Can't use something like "me" or "this" keyword in wf4 xaml activity?

Tags: c#, xaml, this, workflow-foundation-4

We have implemented a class `ActivityException`, where the constructor accepts (amongst others) an argument of type `System.Activities.Activity`. This argument is used to create an error message that contains `Activity.DisplayName` and `Activity.Id`.

This works very fine for WF4 activities written in C#. Here I can use something like:

```
throw new ActivityException(this, ...)
```

But now I am implementing a WF4 activity in xaml format (i.e. using workflow editor). If I throw an exception here, I have to use the `System.Activities.Statements.Throw` activity. I filled the `Exception` parameter of this activity as follows:

```
new ActivityException(Me, ...)
```

But the workflow editor says: "'Me' is valid only within an instance method".

I also tried 'this' instead of 'Me', but this produces an error message, too.

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If the form name is MainWindow for example you could do:
`MainWindow mw = new MainWindow;
new ActivityException(mw, ...)`

Comment: But with this approach I would hand over another activity instance to the `ActivityException`, not the "own" instance. As a result, the `ActivityException` would read the wrong `Activity.Id` when creating its error message.

Answer (score 0):

Even if such a thing eventually worked, the `Me` you were trying to access would be the `Thrown` activity and not any other. Moreover, it seems you're using exceptions to log something (?). That's not how you do such a thing.

Not knowing what you're trying to do I would advice you to take a step back a consider other approach. Two options:

1) Create your own activity, which receives said DisplayName and throws an exception:

```
public class ThrownActivityException : CodeActivity
{
    [RequiredArgument]
    public InArgument<string> ActivityDisplayName { get; set; }

    public override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        var displayName = ActivityDisplayName.Get(context);

        throw new ActivityException(displayName);
    }
}
```

2) Second option, and probably what you want. Considering you're trying to access runtime information (activity's Id) for logging purposes, check [Workflow Tracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee513992%28VS.100%29.aspx) and its capabilities.

Comment: > Even if such a thing eventually worked, the Me you were trying to access would be the Thrown activity and not any other  -> that's what I have feared :-)

Comment: 1. Create your own activity: OK, but what's the advantage of creating an own activity compared to using Microsoft's `Throw` activity? In both cases I have to implement a new `ActivityException` ctor that accepts a string instead of an activity.

Comment: 2. Use Workflow Tracking: We already use tracking, but only if we manually activate it at our customer. We don't use automatic tracking that is active all the time (for performance reasons).

Comment: We use the `ActivityException`, because we want to have additional information in case of exceptions. By adding the `Activity.Id` in the exception message, we can distinguish error sources in case the faulty activity appears more than once within the workflow.